# Debian's apache configuration. fcgid or proxy fastcgi + php fpm

Tags: apache-2.2, php-fpm, mod-fcgid, mod-proxy-fcgi

I'm trying to figure out, what would be better solution. I have a server with arout 10 vhosts. Now, its configured like in this tutorial: http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-apache2-with-mod_fcgid-and-php5-on-debian-squeeze but I'm wondering if proxy_fastcgi + php fpm wouldn't be better. Also, I don't know how to configure proxy_fastcgi and php_fpm for vhosts and using different user:group on different vhosts.

Anyway, which one will be better in my situation?

Comment: What's your concrete answerable question? Please choose **one** problem only.

Comment: The main question is about chosing fcgid or fastcgi + php fpm of course.